# eso - survive Warrior starfall as stam

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I usually play mag sorc in vet trials but I got bored and want to switch to stam nb. Before going "whaaat???" yes I do know is easier to sustain as mag, you have better aoe etc. But I like my nb more, have better single target dps than most mags I played with (I hit about 40k single target fully buffed with horn rotation) so I am better at bosses.

**Now the issue**... most things are manageable after you get used to them (in AA after you learned the right positioning you have little to no trouble, in SO the same, MOL is MOL you die whatever you do :)) ). The thing I wanna get my head around before trying it is how to survive warrior starfall in vHRC. As a mag is simple you just spam shield. As a stam you should theoretically be able to block but since that thing hits for like 15-17k after you block 3-4 waves you get out of stamina and... die.

I'm thinking to use bone shield (since is cheap) + block until I go to like 1/3 of total stam but don't know if that would keep me alive (bone shield give me 30% hp and from my 17k I get about 5k... not really that much - especially if you compare to a sorc shield that goes around 30k). I could also throw a mirage on bar, and combined with bone shield and block should keep me alive but wasting to skill slots for this will loose me a decent amount of dps (I normally have 1 flex spot on my bar). Since is not exactly easy to test (is last boss and having 11 ppl wait me to test the best way to survive is not exactly polite)... any1 found a decent way to survive that?

Same could apply for AA second boss and MOL first boss but those can actually be outhealed. Warrior hits like a truck, outhealing that would drain healers of resources pretty quick.

Comment: Haven't ran Veteran Trials (or any Trials in general) for probably about a year, so I'm not 100% up to date, but 17k health is certainly too low. Even for our non-veteran newbie raids we always required everyone to bring at least 18k-19k health, no matter their class or role. Also you should add some details on your raid group. Is this something organized, a random pick up, etc.? Are you timing your Ultimates for damage reduction?

Comment: @Mario As you will probably find out later that extra 1k is almost nothing and for it you pay with 1-4k dps. In a vet setup each class needs to do its thing (2 low dps = wipe - because of boss "timers", be in the wrong place = dead - no matter if you have 15k or 25k health). Is skill based not zerg based. I think the only decent gear that would hit 18-19k is tbs and that is still a minor dps loss. There are stages (like the one I describe) where you need to survive on your own for a few seconds. Those seconds usually include attacks that you must block/dodge or shield. The extra 1k is nothing.

Comment: With very precise coordinated positioning from the whole group the healers can ult and healing springs through it. If you are left to survive that attack on your own there's not much you can do besides conserve stamina. The final phase is not a dps race. If you have to heavy attack a lot instead of using your stamina potions on cooldown just to make sure you start each phase with pot ready and full stamina, do it.

Comment: @jw013 Just did it today, 14k stamina was all I needed to get through the phase (was just writing my answer when I seen your comment). The tip is good, you jusst don't need full stam.

Comment: Sidenote... can you guys pls. explain the -1 on question? I'm ok with the - rep and I would love to improve my posts, but can't do it if you don't say what you didn't like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the boss today and actually found 2 ways of doing it (one way I did it, and 1 way another stam dd did it).

The way I did it:

- sloted bone shield
- sloted mirage
- took care that at each phase I had over 14k stam
- blocked and used bone shield (really important is not to overcast since is waste of stam)
- stayed in healers range (this was kind of clear but still worth mentioning)

The way the other dd did it:

- sloted vigor
- used vigor when warrior was casting the starfall
- blocked
- stayed in healers range
- he had about 19k hp (2k more) than myself so I guess he ran a 5-1-1 build (I wear 7-0-0) and the extra def + the hp compensated for lack of shield

Results: I died once at first starfall (had only 10k stam, since it was my first run as melee didn't know how much to hold), while mantaining a decent 25k dps (yes, is not a mindblowing dps but as I haven't done it before I had no idea how to position, when to push and when to defence so I played more... prudent; I think next run will go better). The other dd died twice (have no idea why).

Next run I'll make hm, I think that same ways are viable.